# Special Characters introduced into the files when uploaded to SFTP using Blogical adapter

Tags: sftp, biztalk, biztalk-2009

We have a BizTalk 2009 solution which will fetch the files from FTP, do the processing and finally move to a SFTP .

We found the files recently moved to SFTP started getting some special characters.

> for e.g. `J¥§2qPTA |9Çô vœÅÖû}kky/A   FÐíàw±\l«^6 Ý`

We are using the SFTP `Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp`.

How do we stop these characters from being introduced?

Comment: What encoding is the source file?  Is it the same as the transferred file?

Comment: Note: The strange characters caused some interesting issues in StackOverflow being discussed here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335797/an-invalid-xml-character-in-rss-feed-for-question-with-unusual-characters-in-i?cb=1

Comment: @Dijkgraaf ASCII is the encoding type we are using.

Comment: And you have verified that the files before they are picked up are only ASCII and don't contain any special characters?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf We archive the files to file system which seems to be fine whereas the files moved to SFTP only has this issue. That's why we suspect there will be some issues with SFTP adapter not File adapter.

Comment: You are going to have to investigate what changed in your environment.  Did you apply any windows updates, did you install any other software.  Also verify that the source files with a Hex editor to and check the Byte Order Mark in the files.  Have these changed.

Comment: Also try it out in another BizTalk environment with the same files.  Does it exhibit the same behavior there?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf we have 3 environments all of them having the same issue. None of these machine has got patches or updates applied. We consider this strange since the issue started recently with nothing changed.

Comment: Something must have changed.  Have you tried dropping a file you have created in something like Notepad in?